# apply custom function to data.frame row by row without loop in R

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I have the follwing custom function:

```
eulerLotka <- function(l1, l2, l3, m1, m2, m3, x1, x2, x3){

  #this is the Lotka-Euler-Eq -z and z becomes 1 as uniroot finds a 0-value
  y <- function(r, l1, l2, l3, m1, m2, m3, x1, x2, x3, z){((l1*m1*exp(-r*x1)) + (l2*m2*exp(-r*x2)) + (l3*m3*exp(-r*x3))) - z}

    # uniroot finds a 0 value, so offset function, thats why -z in the upper formula
    r <- uniroot(y, l1=l1, l2=l2, l3=l3, m1=m1, m2=m2, m3=m3, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3, z = 1, interval = c(-10, 10))$root #writing only the result of r into variable

  # return r into table
  return(r)

} #end of eulerLotka function
```

I already capture NAs and total-0-rows, which I excluded in this example. 
When I apply this function to my `data.frame` like the following, `uniroot` throws an error:

```
my_data$population_growth_rate <- eulerLotka(my_data$survival_c1, my_data$cum_survival_c2, my_data$cum_survival_c3, my_data$offspring_c1, my_data$offspring_c2, my_data$offspring_c3, my_data$day_c1, my_data$day_c2, my_data$day_c3)
```

But if I call the function within a loop, it works fine:

```
for (i in 1:length(my_data$beaker_NO)){
  my_data$population_growth_rate[i] <- eulerLotka(my_data$survival_c1[i], my_data$cum_survival_c2[i], my_data$cum_survival_c3[i], my_data$offspring_c1[i], my_data$offspring_c2[i], my_data$offspring_c3[i], my_data$day_c1[i], my_data$day_c2[i], my_data$day_c3[i])
}
```

Why is it so, and what can I do to call the function without a loop?

I already tried `apply` and `mapply` that I found while searching for a solution. Both without success (`uniroot` again throws an error).

I guess I missed something stupid, but cannot find it. I would appreciate any idea or help :)

EDIT:
Here's my_data as requested (hope this is the right way to post):

```
structure(list(beaker_NO = 1:120, treat_comp = structure(c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("Dm_LM0", "Dm_LM10", "Dm_LM100", "Dm_LM15", "Dm_LM20", 
"Dm_LM5", "Dm_UM0", "Dm_UM10", "Dm_UM100", "Dm_UM15", "Dm_UM20", 
"Dm_UM5"), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), .Label = c("0_Scen_LM", "0_Scen_UM", "10_Scen_LM", "10_Scen_UM", 
"100_Scen_LM", "100_Scen_UM", "15_Scen_LM", "15_Scen_UM", "20_Scen_LM", 
"20_Scen_UM", "5_Scen_LM", "5_Scen_UM"), class = "factor"), repl_NO = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), X1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X4 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), 
    X5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), 
    X6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), 
    X7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), 
    X8 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), 
    X9 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 
    1L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 
    4L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 5L), .Label = c("", "07. Jan", "1", "10", 
    "11", "12", "13. Jan", "14", "9", "x"), class = "factor"), 
    X10 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
    4L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "10", "11", "5", "6", 
    "7", "8", "9", "x"), class = "factor"), X11 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1L, 2L, NA, 12L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 
    3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X12 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("", 
    "1", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "x"), class = "factor"), 
    X13 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 
    8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0/1", "11", "12", "13", 
    "3", "8", "x"), class = "factor"), X14 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "11", "x"), class = "factor"), X15 = structure(c(1L, 6L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "0/1", "1", "10", "3", "x"), class = "factor"), X16 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 
    11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 
    7L, 8L, 5L), .Label = c("", "08. Jan", "09. Jan", "1", "10", 
    "10. Jan", "11", "12", "5", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
    X17 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), X18 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "03. Jan", "2", 
    "3", "4", "8"), class = "factor"), X19 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 
    7L), .Label = c("", "10", "10. Jan", "11", "11. Jan", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "9", "x"), class = "factor"), X20 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    day_c1 = c(21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, NA, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    11, 21, 12, 21, 21, 21, 11, 11, 9, 11, 10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 
    9.5, 10, 10, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 
    21, 21, 21, 11, 21, 11, 11, 21, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
    9, 9, 9), day_c2 = c(21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    NA, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 15, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 12, 14, 13, 12.5, 
    13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 15, 21, 21, 21, 
    15, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12.5, 12, 13, 12.5, 12, 12), day_c3 = c(21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, NA, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 18, 18, 21, 18, 
    16, 18, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 17, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 17, 17, 17, 21, 17, 21, 17, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15.5, 16, 16, 16, 16), offspring_c1 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 12, 12, 6, 14, 7, 5, 9, 
    10, 11, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 3, 0, 3, 10, 12, 10, 
    9, 7, 10, 8, 11, 13, 11), offspring_c2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 11, 8, 17, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 11, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 13, 12, 11, 13, 13, 
    12, 13, 15, 14), offspring_c3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 2, 0, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 8, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    5, 4, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 11, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 7, 11, 12, 10
    ), undev_eggs_or_dead_born_c1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), undev_eggs_or_dead_born_c2 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0), undev_eggs_or_dead_born_c3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), day_of_death = c(21L, 15L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 
    13L, 9L, 6L, 21L, 21L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 8L, 14L, 21L, 21L, 
    8L, 21L, 21L, 21L, NA, 21L, 6L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 6L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 6L, 12L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 21L, 6L, 19L, 13L, 
    13L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 21L, 15L, 7L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 6L, 21L, 
    21L, 7L, 6L, 21L, 5L, 6L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 7L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 7L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L
    ), survival_c1 = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, NA, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 
    0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1), survival_c2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), survival_c3 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), cum_survival_c2 = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, NA, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
    0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), cum_survival_c3 = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, NA, 0.7, 0.7, 
    0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
    0.9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), survival_total = c(0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, NA, 0.7, 
    0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
    0.9, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), population_growth_rate = c(-0.548253280611676, 
    -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, 
    -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, 
    -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, 
    -0.482227712193977, -0.482227712193977, -0.482227712193977, 
    -0.482227712193977, -0.482227712193977, -0.482227712193977, 
    -0.482227712193977, -0.482227712193977, -0.482227712193977, 
    -0.482227712193977, -0.455588251976892, -0.455588251976892, 
    -0.455588251976892, -0.455588251976892, NA, -0.455588251976892, 
    -0.455588251976892, -0.455588251976892, -0.455588251976892, 
    -0.455588251976892, -0.443604910088864, -0.443604910088864, 
    -0.443604910088864, -0.443604910088864, -0.443604910088864, 
    -0.443604910088864, -0.443604910088864, -0.443604910088864, 
    -0.443604910088864, -0.443604910088864, 0.0732504452718779, 
    -0.438585510194361, 0.0630203252486924, -0.438585510194361, 
    3.05175781232237e-05, -0.438585510194361, 0.0610329340997982, 
    0.0385086076720785, 3.05175781232237e-05, 0.0997535394873194, 
    0.320665252448158, 0.263992429172323, 0.245636890618122, 
    0.333716575510355, 0.261623823826246, 0.250156804597224, 
    0.291453243444366, 0.289101944297742, 0.285745201520734, 
    0.278889498531854, -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, 
    -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, 
    -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, 
    -0.548253280611676, -0.548253280611676, -0.495940836214367, 
    -0.495940836214367, -0.495940836214367, -0.495940836214367, 
    -0.495940836214367, -0.495940836214367, -0.495940836214367, 
    -0.495940836214367, -0.495940836214367, -0.495940836214367, 
    -0.471584005671505, -0.471584005671505, -0.471584005671505, 
    -0.471584005671505, -0.471584005671505, -0.471584005671505, 
    -0.471584005671505, -0.471584005671505, -0.471584005671505, 
    -0.471584005671505, -0.449211272694424, 0.0276500457436783, 
    -0.449211272694424, -0.449211272694424, -0.449211272694424, 
    -0.449211272694424, -0.449211272694424, -0.449211272694424, 
    -0.449211272694424, -0.0148842546964249, 3.05175781232237e-05, 
    -0.438585510194361, -0.438585510194361, 0.0946652221771135, 
    0.123797410919051, 0.0646217990911813, 0.126026108030958, 
    0.124789630103426, -0.438585510194361, 0.133570171501455, 
    0.315069928471503, 0.321809820397907, 0.307588632905269, 
    0.299613831920816, 0.286072252121948, 0.311803578708894, 
    0.269097760860433, 0.312118094806563, 0.331347291564091, 
    0.317866549798655)), row.names = c(NA, -120L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT 2:
If you like to try with original data, you have to use the following version of the custom function:

```
eulerLotka <- function(l1, l2, l3, m1, m2, m3, x1, x2, x3){

  #if one of those values is NA, return NA and don't calculate anything
  if(is.na(l1) || is.na(l2) || is.na(l3) || is.na(m1) || is.na(m2) || is.na(m3) || is.na(x1) || is.na(x2) || is.na(x3)){
    return (NA)
  }
  # if all 3 values of a parameter are 0, the function will set one to 0.0001 (otherwise it won't work)
  if(l1 == 0 && l2 == 0 && l3 == 0){
    l3 <- 0.0001
  }
  if(m1 == 0 && m2 == 0 && m3 == 0){
    m3 <- 0.0001
  }
  if(x1 == 0 && x2 == 0 && x3 == 0){
    x3 <- 0.0001
  }

  #this is the Lotka-Euler-Eq -z and z becomes 1 as uniroot finds a 0-value
  y <- function(r, l1, l2, l3, m1, m2, m3, x1, x2, x3, z){((l1*m1*exp(-r*x1)) + (l2*m2*exp(-r*x2)) + (l3*m3*exp(-r*x3))) - z}

    # uniroot finds a 0 value, so offset function, thats why -z in the upper formula
    r <- uniroot(y, l1=l1, l2=l2, l3=l3, m1=m1, m2=m2, m3=m3, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3, z = 1, interval = c(-10, 10))$root #writing only the result of r into variable

  # return r into table
  return(r)

} #end of eulerLotka function
```

Comment: Please provide `my_data` with `dput()` function.

Comment: see edit. not sure whether this is ok, this way. Never used dput() before

Comment: Are you sure it is working? I have following error: `f() values at end points not of opposite sign `.

Comment: Yep. That's the error. But not with a loop... then it is working... But in that case you have to escape NAs and full-0-lines.... wait a sec - I'll edit this as well

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `purrr::pmap()` function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

my_data$population_growth_rate <-
  my_data %$%
  pmap_dbl(list(
      survival_c1, cum_survival_c2, cum_survival_c3,
      offspring_c1, offspring_c2, offspring_c3,
      day_c1, day_c2, day_c3
    ),
    eulerLotka
  )
```

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, this is even more complicated and more code, than just writing a loop. I think there should be another solution. When I just have a simple formula like l1+m1+x1 the one line-approach works fine. It's just the uniroot function that has problems with this way, somehow. But thanks for the idea! But why is this working this way, and not the "default"-way?

Comment: Because your function does not include vectorization. You can just rewrite your function with loop logic inside. Then it will work as you want.

Comment: hmm.. But the problem with vectorization should be solved e.g. with mapply() and it still doesn't work. Unfortunately, with loop inside is also not what I'm looking for, because of transferability for other issues, that I will face in future :/